# How to bake ambient occlusion using custom split normals

Tags: rendering, modifiers, texture-baking, baking, ambient-occlusion

i have custom normal in purple line,
[image: custom normal]

when i bake ao to vertex ,it used vertex normal instead(blue line),and ao is not like a ball-shape leaf ao

[image]